# Android llvm linker

Tags: android, linker, lld

I heard the Android llvm toolchain use mclinker. But the llvm default linker is lld during its early development stage. Anyone know if it will use lld when lld is mature or plan to keep going with mclinker and enhance mclinker in future.

Jonathan